# Error when installing glassfish server on windows server

Tags: java, glassfish

When i tried to install glassfish server on windows 2008 R2 server, it shows the following error message.JRE already installed in my system and set environment variables as follows

JAVA_HOME - C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17
CLASSPATH - %JAVA_HOME%\jre\lib
Path - ;%JAVA_HOME%\bin

Your help will be highly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Did you try the option suggested by the dialog?

Comment: Was it glassfish open source edition or glassfish eterprise? We have tried to install open source edition on WS 2008 with no success and we found somewhere (sorry it's late ad I don't remember where), that WS 2008 is not supported by glassfish open source. So, we tried with enterprise edition and it worked like a charm (very predictible, I know ;)

Answer (score 1):

You just need to set the "JAVA_HOME" environment variable (at least in my installation it was enough).

In 64 operating systems you must install from a command line. The command should be something like `C:\Installer>glassfish-4.0-windows.exe -j "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45"`

You just need to change to your actual glassfish installer version and jdk home.

Answer (score 0):

One can use C:\directory_of_glassfish_exe start glassfish-4.0-windows.exe -j "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45"